# Cannot access s3 file from Flink in AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, amazon-emr

We have a long running Flink cluster on AWS EMR. It is configured with the default roles (EMR_EC2_DefaultRole).
We try to run a Flink job but it cannot access the s3 bucket to read a file.
We have created the minimal main method code to reproduce it:

```
String filePath = "s3://<our-bucket>/<the-file>";
logger.info("Path: " + filePath);
Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
logger.info("Successfully got path");
File file = path.toFile();
logger.info("Successfully got creds file");
logger.info("Exists [{}], isFile [{}] ", file.exists(), file.isFile());
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
logger.info("Content [{}]", content);
```

We run the Flink job via the Flink Web UI.
We get all the logs except the `Content` log.

The exists log is: `Exists [false], isFile [false]`

We also get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 's3:/<our-bucket>/<the-file>' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:299)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(FileUtils.java:1711)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(FileUtils.java:1748)
    at com.<our-package>.Main.main(Main.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:529)
    ... 10 more
```

When we ssh to the master EC2 instance and run the following command it works and returns the file content:

```
sudo hdfs dfs -cat s3://<our-bucket>/<the-file>
```

Please help :)

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the single '/' in your FileNotFoundException. Can you triple check that you provide the correct URL?

Comment: @ArvidHeise I've checked it and this happens because of the line `Paths.get(filePath)`. When the `path` object is logged that is what it produces. I cannot change this line since it is a line inside a 3rd party library I am using. I've tried to pass a url that starts with `s3:///` but it removes all the duplicate slashes

Comment: What happens if you use `s3a://<bucket>` or `s3n://<bucket>`?

Comment: @kkrugler same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to pass an S3 path to `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString()`, which I don't think will work.

You can create a Flink `Path` from that S3 path and use that to create an input stream, e.g.

```
Path = new Path("s3://<our-bucket>/<the-file>");
FileSystem fs = filePath.getFileSystem();
InputStream is = new DataInputStream(fs.open(filePath, readBufferSize));
String s = IOUtils.toString(is, charset);
```

Comment: Yes this would probably work, the problem is I cannot change this code since it is a 3rd party I have to use. (see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59609433/cannot-access-s3-file-from-flink-in-aws-emr/59673470#comment105389241_59609433))

Comment: Then you're out of luck, unless you use something like [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse). Note that this has nothing to do with Flink, it's a pure AWS/S3 issue.